# What went wrong in this fake proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fake-proofs

So, I came up with this quite ridiculous fake proof that no nonnegative integers $(x,y)$ satisfy $x^2+y^2=5$. Clearly, $(x,y)=(1,2)$ satisfies the equation, so the proof is wrong; but somehow, I can't find why!

Let $f(x,y):=x^2+y^2-5$. We will prove by induction on $x$ that $f$ has no roots. Base case: when $x=0$, no $y$ satisfies $f(0,y)=0$ since $y^2=5$, but $\sqrt5$ is irrational (recall that $x,y$ are integers). Now suppose $f(x,y)$ has no roots for some particular $x$. We need to show that $f(x+1,y)$ has no roots too. To do this, we take the contrapositive statement: if $f(x+1,y)$ had a root, say $(a,b)$ then $f(x,y)$ has a root too. This is true, since the solution set $(a+1,b)$ works. Since the contrapositive statement is true, the original statement is true too. This completes induction, since $f(0,y)$ has no roots implies $f(1,y)$ has no roots, etc. such that $f(x,y)$ has no roots for any $x$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "This is true, since the solution set $(a + 1, b)$ works." What do you mean by this? Where specifically are you using the details of the function $f(x, y)$ in the induction step?

Comment: Why should $f(a,b)=0$ imply $f(a-1,b)=0$? (Also, 5 isn’t irrational)

Comment: Well, $f(a+1,b)=0$ since $x+1=a$ and $y=b$ is a root. But like you said, the specific properties of $f$ are not used at all, so this seems a ridiculous conclusion, but I cannot pinpoint why.

Comment: @Fede yes, I meant $\sqrt5$ is irrational.

Comment: $f(a,b)=a^2+b^2-5=0$, but $f(a-1,b)=(a-1)^2+b^2-5=a^2-2a+1+b^2-5=1-2a$, which is clearly not 0 for any integer $a$

Comment: Yes, I mean $(a+1,b)$ is a root to $f(x-1,y)$, which is trivially true (here, $(a,b)$ is a root for $f(x,y)$)

Comment: Or if this makes it clearer, $(a+1,b)$ is a root of $g(x,y):=f(x-1,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should really focus on your last sentence, since that shows what goes wrong.  Correctly, there are no integers $y$ with $f(0,y)=5$.  However, as you point out, there is an integer $y$ with $f(1,y)=5$, but your argument says there isn't.

Your error comes from thinking that you can take a supposed root $y_0$ for $f(1,y)$ and simply move the $x$-coordinate down and preserve the root, thereby showing that $y_0$ is a root for $f(0,y)$.   This isn't so because $f(1,y)=y^2-4$ isn't the same thing as $f(0,y)=y^2-5$.  Or, said differently, the function $f(x+1,y)$ and $f(x,y)$ are completely different.  If you know that $f(x_0,y_0)=0$, why in the world should $f(x_0-1,y_0)$ also equal $0$?  There is no reason.

What you are likely thinking:  if $(a,b)$ is a root for $f(x,y)$, then $(a+1,b)$ is a root for $f(x-1,y)$.  True, but not what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using induction on the parameter $x$. That's OK for me, but for the fact that I don't see I you could work with it. The problem is, the hypothesis should be "$P(x)$ : $f(x,y)$ has no root (meaning, no $y$ root)".

I think your problem is that you don't define clearly what you understand has a "root" for a multivariate polynomial. Those polynomials may have infinitely many roots... if you call "root" a couple $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Does redefining "root" and stating clearly when I mean a "some $y$ that satisfies.." or "some duple $(x,y)$" so that.." really solve the problem in the proof though?

Comment: No it won't. If you induce on $x$, you fix it, so you can't use your trick.